# draw image, like a human is making using Pencil

Tags: android

I want to use a animation in my application that draw image slowly-2 like a human being is making using pencil. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hello nik...i am using a animation to show a image. This is a alpha animation but i need a animation that draw that image from x=0 to y=end

Comment: it should be sketching using a pencil

Comment: i got it, it is good thing to more elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of points that represent such a drawing, just draw a line on a canvas, adding the points in one by one over time, in an animation thread.

I like to draw circles for the points that are closer together than the width of the line (it looks less jagged)...

Something like this:

```
for (Point pB : points) {
        if(pB == null){
            pA = null;
            continue;
        }
        double dist = getDistance(pA,pB);

        if(pA != null && dist > lineWidth){ 
            canvas.drawCircle(pB.x, pB.y, (float)lineWidth, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(pA.x, pA.y, pB.x, pB.y, paint);
        }
        else
            canvas.drawCircle(pB.x, pB.y, (float)lineWidth, paint);

        pA = pB;            
        // //Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
    }
```

points would be a temporary list of Point that you would keep adding to from your master list that represented the entire drawing.

EDIT:

So, you have an array of points that is your entire drawing

```
Point [] myDrawing{a,b,c,d,e,f.........};
```

and a Paint that defines the line

Paint paint = new Paint();// set all the values for what the line should look like

then you start an animation thread that sleeps for 50 milliseconds and every time it wakes up it draws 1 more point from your drawing like this..

```
Thread draw = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
       int curPoint = 0;
       while(curPoint < myDrawing.length){
          //call the drawing loop I defined above but modify it to only use points 0 - curPoint
        drawPointsZeroThroughCurPoint(curPoint);
        ++curPoint;
        sleep(50);
       }
}

    }

};

draw.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time dredel but can you tell me how i can sketch a image like a animation

Comment: I edited my answer with more details. You should have everything you need to figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some form of path with a list of points, and then move the "pencil" from the first to the last.
Read about linked lists in java, it's easy and everything will be clear. The only problem is making the path. You might have to write some tool in your pc to transform images into paths.
Another way to achieve this effect, but a bit bolder, is to pick random points in the edges of the picture, sort them, and then move the pencil from the beginning to the end.

Comment: Thanks alfa it may be happen...but i am new to android so for me it is impossible but anyway thanks for your time